# Regex for a multiline string with PHP preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to build a pattern for a multiline string, that must start with `<?php` or `whitespace` + `<?php` and **NOT** end with `?>` or `?>` + `whitespace`.

My attempt was `/^\s?<\?php.*[^>]\s?$/s` but it did not work. Also tried the negative lookahead - no use.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just `trim()` the string first, this gets a lot easier and could be done with simple `str_pos` calls

Comment: Not possible in my case. Here I just prepare patterns to pass them over to another script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
(?s)^\s*<\?php(?!.*\?>\s*$).*+$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gJ1eN9/10)

**Regex explanation:**

- `(?s)` - Enable singleline mode for the whole pattern for `.` to match newline
- `^` - Start of string
- `\s*` - Optional whitespace, 0 or more repetitions
- `<\?php` - Literal `<?php`
- `(?!.*\?>\s*$)` - Look-ahead checking if the string does not end with `?>whitespace`
- `.*+$` - Matches without backtracking any characters up to the string end.

The [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) (as in `.*+`) enables us to consume characters once, in 1 go, and never come back in search of possible permutations.

> Possessive quantifiers are a way to prevent the regex engine from
>   trying all permutations. This is primarily useful for performance
>   reasons.

And we do not to use explicit SKIP-FAIL verbs then.

Comment: I think OP wants **NOT end with `?>` or `?>whitespace*`**

Comment: Yes it works though I am not a fan of double negative lookbehind. However honestly I didn't downvote your answer someone else did.

Comment: @anubhava: Now it should

Comment: Yes now it does and much better than 2 lookbehinds +1

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, you can use this regex:

```
'/^\s*<\?php(?:.(?!\?>\s*$))*$/s'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eY7wS9/1)

- `^\s*<\?php` matches optional whitespaces and literal `<?php` at line start.
- `(?:.(?!\?>\s*$))*` will match any 0 or more characters that don't end with `?>whitespace*` using a negative lookahead.

---

**Update:** For efficiency this PCRE regex will perform faster than the previous one:

```
'/^\s*<\?php(?>.*\?>\s*$(*SKIP)(*F)|.*+$)/s'
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/eY7wS9/3)

- `(*FAIL)` behaves like a failing negative assertion and is a synonym for `(?!)`
- `(*SKIP)` defines a point beyond which the regex engine is not allowed to backtrack when the subpattern fails later
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` together provide a nice alternative of restriction that you cannot have a variable length lookbehind in above regex.